# How to add the "default user session" to a custom group

Tags: wakanda

Is it possible to add the default user session whos user name is "default guest" to a custom group (ex. Guest) to be able to make use of the Wakanda class permissions?

[image]

Or group methods like this?

```js
currentSession().belongsTo('Guest') // true
```

Comment: Try adding the "default user" to a group. You can retrieve the object with `currentUser().user`. Then use the API to add it one time to a group like "Anonymous". Those permissions are available only for groups, so if you are able to add the default user to any group, you can manage his permissions.

Comment: added `currentSession().user.putInto(['Guest']);` to my bootstrap file, but this doesn't do the trick. also `currentSession().promoteWith('Guest');` in the bootstrap file does not work? any help is much appreciated

Comment: You can create a mock "anonymousUser" and log in the user at application start if it's anonymous with that user. Then add the privileges to it.

Comment: This is what I did as a workaround, but it looks like there is no other option. Thanks anyway for all the help.

Comment: Don't worry. I'll add it as an answer since it's the only solution available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately a documented way to alter the permissions of an anonymous user is not available at the moment.

An alternative way consist into creating a custom *"anonymousUser"*, add it the custom *"Guest"* group and modify the *"Guest"* group permissions attaching to it the desired restrictions.

This custom anonymousUser should be logged in at the application start/page view emulating the behavior of anonymous user.